# Django ListView with multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**How do I create a list view that calls multiple classes/models from my model.py file?**

I have created my project, and app and my models. The models use a one-to-many relationship.

I am able to create a listview based on calling a single model, but not using multiple models (in this scenario 7 models).

Here are the models I want to call, with the the required model values that I want displayed in the listview are denoted by **:

```
class TypeAchievement(models.Model):
  typeAchievementID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="TypeAchievementID")
  languageCodeID = models.ForeignKey(LanguageCode, db_column="LanguageCodeID")
  **typeAchievementDescriptionIntl = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="TypeAchievementDescriptionIntl")**
  typeAchievementDescriptionEng = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="TypeAchievementDescriptionEng")
  typeAchievementAltID = models.IntegerField(db_column="TypeAchievementAltID")
  class Meta:
    db_table="TypeAchievement"

class RIAchievement(models.Model):
  riAchievementID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="RIAchievementID")
  userLanguageVersionID = models.ForeignKey(UserLanguageVersion, db_column="UserLanguageVersionID")
  typeAchievementID = models.ForeignKey(TypeAchievement, db_column="TypeAchievementID")
  **riAchievementTypeUserDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column="RIAchievementTypeUserDescription")**
  **riAchievementDescription = models.TextField(max_length=2000, db_column="RIAchievementDescription")**
  auth_user_id = models.ForeignKey(auth_user, db_column="auth_user_id")
  class Meta:
    db_table="RIAchievement"

class UserLanguageVersion(models.Model):
  userLanguageVersionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="UserLanguageVersionID")
  auth_user_id = models.ForeignKey(auth_user, db_column="auth_user_id")
  languageCodeID = models.ForeignKey(LanguageCode, db_column="LanguageCodeID")
  class Meta:
    db_table="UserLanguageVersion"

class auth_user(models.Model):
  **auth_user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="id")**
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, db_column="username")
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column="first_name")
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column="last_name")
  email = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column="email")
  password = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_column="password")
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(db_column="is_staff")
  is_active = models.BooleanField(db_column="is_active")
  is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(db_column="is_supervisor")
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(db_column="last_login")
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(db_column="date_joined")
  class Meta:
    db_table="auth_user"

class LanguageCode(models.Model):
  languagecodeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="LanguageCodeID")
  **languageCodeDescription = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="LanguageCodeDescription")**
  baseLanguageCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="BaseLanguageCode")
  languageNameEng = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="LanguageNameEng")
  altLanguageNameEng = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column="AltLanguageNameEng")
  **languageNameNative = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="LanguageNameNative")**
  altLanguageNameNative = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column="AltLanguageNameNative")
  **iso639_1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, db_column="ISO639_1")**
  iso639_2T = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="ISO639_2T")
  iso639_2B = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="ISO639_2B")
  iso639_X = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="ISO639_X")
  languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(LanguageDirection, default=1, db_column="LanguageDirectionID")
  class Meta:
    db_table="LanguageCode"

class LanguageDirection(models.Model):
  languageDirectionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="LanguageDirectionID")
  **languageDirectionDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="LanguageDirectionDescription")**
  **languageDirDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="LanguageDirDescription")**
  **textAlign = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="TextAlign")**
  **oppositeLanguageDirectionDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="OppositeLanguageDirectionDescription")**
  **oppositeLanguageDirDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="OppositeLanguageDirDescription")**
  **oppositeTextAlign = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="OppositeTextAlign")**
  class Meta:
    db_table="LanguageDirection"

class Flag(models.Model):
  flagID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="FlagID")
  languageCodeID = models.ForeignKey(LanguageCode, db_column="LanguageCodeID")
  **flagIconPath = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="FlagIconPath")**
  flagDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="FlagDescription")
  flagInformation = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="FlagInformation")
  class Meta:
    db_table="Flag"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get linked objects from the main one. In your case - iterate over list of `RIAchievement` and get other data as `{{ riachievement.userLanguageVersionID.languageCodeID.languageDirectionID.textAlign }}`

P.S. Also, please format code [according to pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) even it is autogenerated from the database.

Comment: ilvar, thanks for the answer. The solution you provided is not working for me. Do I have to import any data to display the extra fields? P.S. I was forced to format my laptop, and re-establish my project, which is why this request is so delayed.

Comment: No, you don't need any imports. It should be working because it's pretty straightforward. Show how are you sending achievment list to template and how are you iterating over it in the template.

Comment: Here is how I am iterating:  

    {% if qs %}  
      {% for q in qs %}  
        <td>        
          {{ riachievement.typeAchievementID.typeAchievementDescriptionIntl }}
        </td>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

Comment: This is how I am sending:  
    
    from django.shortcuts import render  
    
    from app_data.models import RIAchievement  
    
    def ri_achievements(request):
      #qs = RIAchievement.objects.all()
      qs = RIAchievement.objects.select_related("typeAchievement").all()
        
      return render(request, 'index.html',{'qs': qs})

Comment: So why are you displaying relatives of `riachievement`, if real varianble from `{% for %}` is `q`?